# How to extract all the hyperlinks attached to the page in a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdftron

Iam trying to get the list of hyperlinks and then replace the text for the hyperlink according to a formalue, but iam unable to extract all the hyperlinks as annotations can somone help me with how to get all the hyperlinks as annotations and are hyperlinks in the annotations ??

**Edit**:

This is exactly what i tried and i was able to find out the annotations and modify them but i have no clue how to get the text that is embedded for the annotation which is visible on the pdf and even to modify that text as the [contentReplacer](https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/html/M_pdftron_PDF_ContentReplacer_AddText.htm)

Documentation clearly states that it only replaces the text which are enclosed in "[" and "]" 
So i want to understand whether PDFTron

1. Can actually gives the visible text for the enclosed annotation ?
2. Can i update the visible text for annotation ?
3. Else can i update any text which is not enclosed with "[" and "]" ?

Comment: Typically hyperlink annotations are not as straightforward as you might expect. There are two common cases. 1) The annotation is completely transparent (though maybe with a visible border) and the text you see is actually part of the page. 2) There is no annotation at all, but the PDF reader program you are using has generated one on the fly, based on the text in the page. In both cases the "text" is actually part of the page. Can you provide an example PDF file that you want to process so it can be reviewed?

Comment: Iam dealing with case -1 pdfs where i do have text that refers to a particular hyperlink internally. How do i extract those ?

Comment: Since the text that user can see, is not necessarily the hyperlink text, then changing the hyperlink is easy. But changing the visible text is much more difficult. "then replace the text for the hyperlink according to a formalue" Do you need to change the visible text? Or just the hyperlink itself?

Comment: The visible text @Ryan can you provide me some sample code if you can please.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the ContentReplacer class to replace the text underneath the hyperlink annotation.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/#contentreplacer

In particular you would use the ContentReplacer.AddText method to pass in a Rect defining the area to be replaced.

You can iterate through the annotations to find the one you want, and then pass the Rect from that Annotation to the ContentReplacer.AddText method.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/#annotation

If you want to get the text underneath the annotation you can do the following.

```
var te = new TextExtractor();
te.Begin(pageAnnotIsOn); // where pageAnnotIsOn is a Page object
string text = te.GetTextUnderAnnot(annot); // where annot is an Annot object
```

Comment: Please check the edit on what i have tried and what i am expecting.

Comment: I updated my answer, to clarify that you want to pass the Rect from the Annotation to the AddText method.

Comment: Can you post a code sample of getting the annotationtext using `GetTextUnderAnnot` ?

Comment: This works perfectly but and i was able to replace the text with contentreplacer but is there any way i could set the threshold for text wrapping as it always exceeds the page and is not visible

Comment: It should wrap within the Rect you defined. Perhaps you should create a new SO question, and include your code, and ideally test file, for further review.